# Sugerencias CCS en Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Porqué no me salen las sugerencias de CSS en Visual Studio Code?
Al ingresar por ejemplo `text` no me salen todas las sugerencias que van de a acuerdo a text. como `text-align` y poder autocompletarlo de manera fácil.
Existe algún plugin o algo parecido para que esto ya no me siga sucediendo?
Gracias!

Comment: ¿El problema es que no te aparecen en el archivo .CSS o en uno .HTML?

Comment: En un css y tambien en un php no me salen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba Instalando esta Extension:

PHP Intelephense (Ben Mewburn)
PHP code intelligence for Visual Studio Code

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego Reinicia el editor utilizando la combinacion de tecla: **CTRL + SHIFT + P**

Tipea en el campo: **reload window**

Crea un archivo PHP, verifica que tenga el identificador de lenguaje en PHP 
(barra inferior derecha)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tipea cualquier etiqueta en HTML y cuando coloques el atributo `style=""` pulsa la combinacion **CTRL + SPACE** y comienzas a tipear el comando para que te ayude en el autocompletado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te comento que es una solucion que **funciona al 60% de su efectividad** porque se pierde entre los comandos de php y no siguiere automaticamente los valores para las reglas css.

En este aspecto Visual Studio Code no es muy bueno al trabajar combinando php / HTML / CSS, he buscado una solucion realmente efectiva pero no hay algo definitivo, dicen que la proxima version ya habra resuelto este problema, en ese aspecto Sublime y Atom llevan la delantera en autocompletacion combinada de codigo.

Otra solucion es: Cuando quieras trabajar solo con codigo HTML / CSS cambias **El modo de Lenguaje a HTML**

Pulsando el modo de lenguaje ubicado en la barra inferior derecha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tipeas HTML lo seleccionas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto cambiara el modo de lenguaje a HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este modo el auto completado de **codigo HTML y CSS** es mucho mas preciso, pero lo malo que se pierde la interpretacion **PHP** por lo que debes repetir el proceso a la inversa al usar codigo PHP.

Comment: Muy completo! Muchas Gracias